# Change all values of a list with new with linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

Perhaps very eash but i dont know linq.

I have an integer list

```
Dim IntList As list (Of Integer) = {90,45,66,66,7,90,20}.tolist
```

I want change some values with new e.g. 90 with 80

```
IntList = {80,45,66,66,7,80,20}
```

How can i do? Thanks

Comment: Linq is for _querying_ not _updating_. If you want to change the list in-place use a `For` loop.  Linq would be appropriate to create a _new_ list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `Select`, like this:

```
Dim Seq = From n In IntList Select If (n=90, 80, n)
Dim Subst As List (Of Integer) = Seq.ToList()
```

`If(<cond>, <on-true>, <on-false>)` will produce 80 when the corresponding item is 90; otherwise, it will produce the unchanged item itself.

Answer (score 1):

Little changed dasblinkenlight's answer.

```
IntList = IntList.Select(Function(x) If(x = 90, 80, x)).ToList
```